# Baselineskip ignored in Beamer footline

Tags: beamer, fontsize, line-spacing

I am using the following to define the footline element of my Beamer presentation:

```
\setbeamerfont{footline}{size=\large}

\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{Institute} %the fontsize changes the size of the footer
{

  \center{\color{algrey}{\noindent\hspace{0cm}\rule[0cm]{\paperwidth}{1pt}}}\\  
   \leavevmode%
 %   \vspace{0.4cm}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=.5em,wd=\paperwidth,ht=4.90ex,dp=1ex,center]{innerbox}%
        % FAU Logo
        %\begin{picture}(100.0,0.0) 
%           \put(290.7,-9.85){\includegraphics[height=0.7cm]{templates/logos/logo_dummy}}
%       \end{picture}
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.400\paperwidth,ht=2ex,dp=0ex,left]{innerbox}%
            {\setstretch{10.0}\fontsize{5}{10}\selectfont \inserttitle \\[4pt] \insertauthor \par}
        \end{beamercolorbox}
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=1.1cm,ht=2ex,dp=0ex,center]{innerbox}%
            {\fontsize{3}{0}\selectfont\textcopyright~\the\year\\[3pt]
            %Page \insertframenumber{}/\inserttotalframenumber{}}
            Page \insertframenumber{}}
        \end{beamercolorbox}
        % Page Counter
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.425\paperwidth,ht=1ex,dp=0ex,right]{innerbox}%
            %{\large Institute}\\
            \vspace{-0.19cm}
            \includegraphics[height=0.7cm]{templates/logos/logo_dummy}
            %{\fontsize{4}{0}\selectfont\copyright~Institute, 2013\\[3pt]
            %Page \insertframenumber{}/\inserttotalframenumber{}}
            % \vspace{-0.5pt}
        \end{beamercolorbox}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}
```

This results in a footer rendered as:

[image: Example Screenshot]

As you can see, the title lines have no whitespace (baselineskip) between them. I tried to

- set `\fontsize{x}{y}\selectfont` to different values
- manually set `\baselineskip`
- change `\setbeamerfont{footline}{size=\large}`
- change the size of the `beamercolorbox`es

however nothing helped separating the two title lines.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is adressed at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/179255 and can be resolved by adding `\normalbaselines` to the code of the footline.